# How to define global filter in Laravel Nova?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-nova

I have a project with users. For each user in Laravel nova, i need to define a different access level. How can this be done in Laravel Nova? Or, for example, a user can have several projects on an account, how can I make a filter for switching between user projects within one account? That is, a certain global filter is needed, where by clicking on the button, all entities, resources, and data available to the user are filtered.

Answer (score 0):

Access level for users in Nova can be provided via Laravel Policies: https://nova.laravel.com/docs/4.0/resources/authorization.html

For global filtering you can play with indexQuery method in Nova resource:
https://nova.laravel.com/docs/4.0/resources/authorization.html#index-filtering